# Why isn't my image showing when retrieved from Firebase eventhough it was successfully uploaded?

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout, firebase-realtime-database

**This is my code.**

```
private void uploadPattern() {
        if (mImageUri != null) {
            final StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));

            mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                        }
                    }, 500);

                    Toast.makeText(PatternArranger.this, "Save Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Upload upload = new Upload(mEditPatternName.getText().toString().trim(),
                            //taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri().toString());
                    //String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                    //mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                    Task<Uri> urlTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                    while ( !urlTask.isSuccessful());
                    Uri downloadUrl = urlTask.getResult();

                    //Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: firebase download url: " + downloadUrl.toString()); //use if testing...don't need this line.
                    Upload upload = new Upload(mEditPatternName.getText().toString().trim(),downloadUrl.toString());

                    String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                    mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                }
            })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(PatternArranger.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            mProgressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No pattern selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

By using a `while` loop, you are likely missing out on important debugging information to solve your issue. In your code, it is likely that `urlTask` has failed and `urlTask.isSuccessful()` will never evaluate to true which is causing an infinite loop.

```
Task<Uri> urlTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
while ( !urlTask.isSuccessful());
```

To fix this, properly attach listeners to the [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html) returned by each operation and log their results.

```
taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri downloadUri) {
      Log.d(TAG, "getDownloadUrl.onSuccess: obtained download URI: " + downloadUri.toString());
      Upload upload = new Upload(mEditPatternName.getText().toString().trim(),downloadUri.toString());

      String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();

      mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
              Log.d(TAG, "setValue.onSuccess: uploaded & saved to database");
              // TODO: Update UI to show image/completion message
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
              // Handle any errors
              Log.d(TAG, "setValue.onFailure: error occured - " + exception.message);
            }
        });
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
      // Handle any errors
      Log.d(TAG, "getDownloadUrl.onFailure: error occured - " + exception.message);
    }
});
```